# how to divide the sum of a groupby value with the count the another value

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I wanted to groupby by 'label' and 'month' to sum the Quantity sold for each month and for each label.

[image: Dataset]

I am trying to do 'groupby and apply' method for achieving this, but not sure how to count the month for each label. Say, for label value AFFLELOU (DOS), I have two values for 7th month. so, I should sum the quantity sold and divide by 2. 
for 9th and 10th month, I just have one value, so the count would be 1 and it would divide the quantity sold.

I wrote the code below, but it doesn't take count as a function and return count not defined error.

```
t1.groupby(['label', 'month']).apply(lambda x: x['Quantity sold'] 
.sum()/count('month'))
```

Can someone tell me how to get the count value of each month for each label?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of summing, counting and dividing, you could use `agg('mean')`:

```
t1.groupby(['label', 'month'])['Quantity sold'].agg('mean')
```

Or, if you do wish to retain the sum and count, use:

```
t1.groupby(['label', 'month'])['Quantity sold'].agg(['sum', 'count', 'mean'])
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(20,3)), columns=['label', 'Quantity sold', 'month'])
t1.groupby(['label', 'month'])['Quantity sold'].agg(['sum', 'count', 'mean'])
```

yields a DataFrame like

```
             sum  count  mean
label month                  
0     1        2      1  2.00
      2        0      1  0.00
      3        2      2  1.00
1     1        1      2  0.50
      2        3      1  3.00
      3        1      1  1.00
2     0        0      1  0.00
      1        0      3  0.00
      3        5      4  1.25
3     0        1      1  1.00
      1        0      1  0.00
      2        0      1  0.00
      3        3      1  3.00
```

---

Using `groupby/agg` with its builtin aggregators `sum`, `count` and `mean` is clearly more convenient here, but if you did need to use `groupby/apply` with a custom function you could use:

```
t1.groupby(['label', 'month']).apply(lambda x: x['Quantity sold'].sum()/len(x))
```

Note that while calling custom functions with `groupby/apply` gives you more flexibility, it comes at a cost because calling a custom Python function once for each group is generally slower than calling the builtin Cythonized aggregators available in `groupby/agg`.

---

If you have missing (`NaN`) values in `Quantity sold`, it may help to know that `group/agg` has both `'count'` and `'size'` aggregators:

- `'count'` returns the number of non-`NaN` values
- `'size'` returns the length of the group (including `NaN` values)

The `count` is always less than or equal to the `size`. The `mean` is the `sum` (of the non-`NaN` values) divided by the `count`. To see the difference between `count` and `size`, you could experiment with this code:

```
np.random.seed(2018)
t1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(50,3)), columns=['label', 'Quantity sold', 'month'])
t1.loc[np.random.choice([True, False], len(t1)), 'Quantity sold'] = np.nan
t1.groupby(['label', 'month'])['Quantity sold'].agg(['sum', 'count', 'size', 'mean'])
```

which yields

```
             sum  count  size      mean
label month                            
0     1      0.0      0     3       NaN
      2      6.0      2     2  3.000000
      3      0.0      0     1       NaN
1     0      3.0      2     5  1.500000
      1      0.0      0     1       NaN
      2      5.0      3     5  1.666667
      3      0.0      2     3  0.000000
2     0      7.0      3     5  2.333333
      1      4.0      4     8  1.000000
      2      5.0      2     3  2.500000
      3      5.0      2     3  2.500000
3     0      1.0      2     5  0.500000
      1      3.0      1     1  3.000000
      2      2.0      1     2  2.000000
      3      2.0      1     3  2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. I tried the same when I was grouping my data after adding the missing dates, which did not give me the results I was expecting. since there are no missing dates added to the dataset, the mean returns the result I was expecting. 
Thanks for clearing and providing the solution :)

Comment: Thanks again@unutbu for the detailed explanation. I needed to add the missing months and then add 0 to it. as of now, I have cleaned my data by removing NaN values. Your solution and explanation will be useful in future when I have missing values. Thanks again :) Much appreciated.

Comment: @Unutbu can you please have a look into my question
[Inline Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083576/pandas-row-filters-and-and-division-from-specific-rows-and-columns/62087141#62087141)